# Generate falling random object to choose from in the array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a game like Tap Tap except the falling objects are randomized. What I'm having problems with right now is if the randomized object got pick again(before it finish moving), It's position would be reset.(this also means two same object won't appear in the screen which I don't want) I figured out a way to solve this is I should be able to create a copy of the movieclip picked but I'm lost. Help?

Also, I'm new to flash. If you have suggestions/advice please tell me! 
Thank you and have a good day.

```
var notes:Array = new Array(NGood1,NGood2,NGood3,NGood4,NGood5,NBad1,NBad2,NBad3,NBad4,NBad5);

var pos1:int;
var pos2:int;
var pos3:int;

pos1 = (stage.stageWidth / 3) -100;
pos2 = (stage.stageWidth / 2) -100;
pos3 = ((stage.stageWidth/3) *2) -100;

var timerN:Timer = new Timer(1000,120);
timerN.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerhandler);
timerN.start();

var secondsN:Number = 1;

function timerhandler(event:TimerEvent)
{
    //trace("Seconds elapsed: " + seconds);
    SpawnNote(null);
    secondsN++;

}


function SpawnNote(event:Event):void
{
    var spawn:int;
    var rpos:int;
    spawn = int(Math.random() * notes.length);
    rpos = int(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    var note:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    note = notes[spawn];
    addChild(note);
    if (rpos ==1)
    {
        note.x = pos1;

    }
    else if (rpos==2)
    {
        note.x = pos2;

    }
    else if (rpos==3)
    {
        note.x = pos3;

    }
    note.y = -20;
    note.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveNote );
    function MoveNote(event:Event):void
    {
        note.y +=  5;
        if (note.y >= stage.stageHeight - 50)
        {
            note.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, StopNote );
            function StopNote(event:Event):void
            {
                note.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveNote );
                //do more
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a "copy of movieclip picked", if you know its class name (the symbol name in Flash CSx). Say you've drawn a good note and named it `NGood1` in the library. Then you need to make a copy of that symbol, you do `var note:MovieClip = new NGood1();` You can make a set of notes to pick from as *classes* in that array of yours, that is, all of the named notes in `notes` array are not objects on the timeline, but class names or symbol names instead (these are the same in terms of Actionscript 3), and to make a copy of a selected `notes[spawn]` symbol, you do `var note:MovieClip = new notes[spawn]();` Note the brackets, these make Flash to call the constructor to make a completely new object.

Another thing that you're not yet doing is proper cleanup. See, you're assigning a `MoveNote` function to each note as an event listener, and to remove that listener you assign **another** event listener on the **same** event (`Event.ENTER_FRAME`) - you should not do this, you instead call `removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveNote);` when you need the note to stop moving.

And another thing to make: once you are in the listener, you need to rely on the `event.target` to find out which of the objects is now working on the event, and you are constantly using `note` variable. Imagine you've added two notes to the stage, now you need to move both of them 5 pixels down per frame. You have there two notes but only **one** of them is stored in your `note` variable, thus, both listeners (you've assigned one to each note, this makes two active) will move one note instead of each one moving its own note. Thankfully you have a means to access the object which is listening from within a particular listener, namely you get the event passed and get its `target` property. Then you move that target (typecast it first if necessary), this will make each note move down at its own speed.

```
var notes:Array = [NGood1,NGood2,NGood3,NGood4,NGood5,NBad1,NBad2,NBad3,NBad4,NBad5];
// this syntax is valid too, and here all the note names are symbol names! 
function SpawnNote(event:Event):void {
    // your code up to creation is intact
    var note:MovieClip = new notes[spawn]();
    addChild(note);
    // again intact code up to listener
    note.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveNote );
} // watch this! You are to put function outside this function, and it's the better
// way of making event listeners for nested objects.
function MoveNote(event:Event):void
{
    var note:DisplayObject=event.target as DisplayObject;
    // get the note being processed, then process as intended
    note.y +=  5;
    if (note.y >= stage.stageHeight - 50)
    {
        note.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveNote );
        //do more
        removeChild(note); // note's out of play
        // If, however, you need to do something for more than a single frame,
        // you may add a listener too, and program corresponding behavior
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I managed to cleaned up my codes a little bit.
But I'm getting errors with var note:MovieClip = new notes[spawn]();
Do I need to remove the movieclips in the timeline?

Here's my code now: http://pastebin.com/3a9acu1X

Comment: Yes you need, because `NGood1` is now not the object name but the class name. Say, you draw a new movie clip and save it to the library, then there's a checkbox "Export for Actionscript", you check it and type the class name which you can then use in your `notes` array. Also, you are again trying to rely on local variables in your `btimerhandler` function, as your `bsecondsN` is located inside a **function** `MoveNote`, not in the main timeline code at the very least. Do pay attention to those curly braces, these signify the availability of objects and their lifetime.

Comment: You should locate your `btimerhandler` listener outside of the `MoveNote` code, like I did with `MoveNote` related to `SpawnNote`. In fact you seemingly want to have your notes to lay down 3 seconds on the "ground" then vanish, but can you tell me what note is to be removed if there are several of them at the ground at the same time?

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do is if the notes reaches the ground, it will stay there for 3 seconds before it vanish. Hmmmm, now I realized the note variable gets over written every time a new note spawn so it's impossible to differentiate it from the others. Btw, I remove the objects in the timeline but I'm getting error #1034. I've already checked the "Export for Actionscript".